# android how to set hyperlink in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to set hyperlink with textview in android so anyone can help me on it.
My code is given below.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Authentication failed. Please visit www.google.com"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Add ID field in the xml and then do so.

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "Authentication Failed . Please visit <a href='http://.www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: How to set String in center programmatically in android

Comment: Pls ask a different question for it. And if you are answered for this question, pls consider upvoting and marking the answer correct.